# How can I get the REAL source code in the browser?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm trying to write a test for a simple API, which always fails because of a strange browser behaviour.

The response coming from the API is just some plain text:

`foo-bar-123`

I can see exactly that in the browser window and also as response in the network tab.

Okay so far, but when I look at the Inspector, I see something like that:

```
<html><head></head><body>foo-bar-123</body></html>
```

If I control the browser with selenium, the result of webdriver.page_source is the same.

For reasons I don't understand, the browser adds some HTML tags to the content.

Is this some strange kind of "feature"? Can this be switched off?

I don't think it's a bug because both Firefox and Chrome are showing this behaviour.

I just want to get the real content without any fancy stuff the browser thinks I need.

Comment: Is it a public url? Do you see the same HTML manually as well as when using Selenium?

Comment: You can test the api directly without using selenium.

Comment: I used selenium with phantomjs some time ago, the behaviour then was exactly like it should be. So my guess is, that Firefox and Chrome are doing crazy things here without a reason.

I'm running other tests which need a browser, so using also selenium for the api seemed to be obvious. But maybe I have to use something else here.

Comment: https://restfulapi.net/content-negotiation/ -> what the format the client expects is shown in browser.  maybe you can fire the get request call on browser and somehow set the Accept to  text/plain. currently i think it is text/html